# Server timeout and sftp timeout. What to do?

Tags: timeout, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Since 12h the website (Wordpress website) that is hosted on Google Cloud Platform has a time out issue. After 60 seconds of trying to load the website, the following message appears "The connection has timed out".

When trying to connect with SFTP, same issue.

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Since two different services stopped to work at the same time it
>   sounds like a networking issue. There is a timeout, therefore there is the server not answering at all to the requests.

What to do?

I would proceed with this general troubleshooting steps, if you want you can upload your question with the result of these commands/question to proceed with the troubleshooting.

- First of all I would check if you are able to ping the
  external/public IP of the instance.
- I would check if the firewall rules allows TCP80/TCP443 and TCP22, Notice that on GCP you need to create the rule and assign the TAG to the machine from its detail page if the the rule does not apply to the whole network.
- Are you able to ssh into the instance?
- I would check if the processes are actually listening `netstat -tuplen`
- If you are able when logged into the machine do you have access to the internet? Are you able to ping external IP? If not whats about internal IP?
- I would go to the "activity" page of your Google Cloud Console to check which actions have been taken while the instance was still running.
- I would check as well the history of the Linux machine to check if you run some commands acting on the network configuration of the machine.

Note that if you cannot SSH into the machine you can always access through serial console setting a password for your username through a startup script.

### UPDATE

I had the possibility to take a look into the project, the machine was stopped due to issue with the billing account (it was closed) after the free trial period ended.

I would suggest you to go again trough the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#end) regarding the upgrade of the billing account

If you have still some doubts or question after you perform this operations you can file a case at this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing?hl=en&cfsi=bronze_contact&cfnti=6186161&cft=3) with the billing team and they will help you to solve the issue.

Comment: 1) Ping result for the external/public IP AND the internal IP: timeout; Packets : Sent=4, Received = 0, Lost=4 (100% loss).
2) no rules have been created yet.
3) yes ssh OK
4) netstat -a : active connections > Proto TCP and UDP
5) not sure what you mean by "when logged into the machine ..."
6) Last activity in Cloud Console dated from 18 October '17
7) I started with free account. Then I enabled billing account and I am receiving monthly bills. I never created any instance. App Engine and Compute Engine are empty.

Comment: How have you deployed your WordPress solution? Regarding the answer "3) SSH ok" to which instance you where trying to access in if you do not have any in compute engine? And in 5) I was suggesting to access the machine and try to send the commands from there

Comment: By the way you can open a private Google issue and I will take a look into your project. Register it here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164  and post in the comment the link (Disclaimer: I work for Google Cloud Platform Support)

Comment: Here you are https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73122752/. Thank you GalloCedrone!

Comment: I answered on the private issue and I updated the question, consider to upvote and accept the answer if it has been useful.

Comment: Thanks GalloCedrone. Thanks to you I found out that something went wrong between two GCP accounts. I upvoted your answer, but nothing happens.

Comment: Do not worry, maybe you do not have enough reputation to do it, it is not a big deal :)

Comment: Dear GalloCedrone, the billing issue is solved. I started the instance. By doing that it got a new external IP address. I configured it in the DNS A name record and I checked thismorning on https://www.whatsmydns.net if it was already propagated and it was. But the website doesn't show up when using domain name or external IP address, and no error message appears. When using internal IP address, I get a timedout error. How can this be solved?